# Работа с формами сайта

Tags: java, telegram

**Здравствуйте, господа!** 
Такой вопрос: как работать с [telegra.ph](http://telegra.ph) без api? 
Просто в ссылке нет параметров. Мне туда надо помещать ботом текст и отдавать ссылку пользователю. 
Заранее благодарю отвечающих!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже появилось API:
http://telegra.ph/api

Также появилась библиотека:
https://github.com/rubenlagus/Telegraph